# How to compute standard deviation for a portfolio in rolling windows?

Tags: python, pandas, finance, portfolio, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe `df` that looks similar to this:

```
Ticker #     1         2            3
0       -0.004530  -0.042642    0.015556    
1        0.040387   0.013036    0.089715    
2       -0.008748  -0.012869    0.024096    
3        0.031440   0.004889    0.033333    
4       -0.008556   0.000000    0.024668
...
1510    -0.009929   -0.008559  -0.009146
```

where the index is date starting at 01-01-2010 (and goes up by trading date) and the columns are returns and the tickers # correspond to 3 different stocks. I also have a similar `df2` of same shape for market capitalization. I'm given 3 rolling windows: 504, 252, 126 and I want to estimate a sample covariance matrix (3 x 3), standard deviation of the portfolio using market cap weights (from the last day of the rolling window) for each period of rolling window length in the sample data, and calculate the one-day ahead return of the portfolio (from mark cap weights and returns from day following the last day in rolling window).

I know how to estimate the sample covariance matrix and SD of the portfolio using `.cov()` and `np.sqrt(np.dot(weights.T, np.dot(cov_matrix, weights)))` (using weights from last row of df2), but I'm not sure how to do this for each period of the rolling windows. Would appreciate any lead!